# Batch execution of SAS using a Telnet connection in Python

Tags: python, sas, telnet, jedit

I have been interested in finding an alternative to the UI in SAS for quite some time now. We license SAS on our server instead of our desktops, so furthermore we have to launch a remote desktop application to execute code.

I was able to use a Telnet connection instead to remotely connect to the server, and batch execute SAS programs. Then I was interested in whether a python script could be made to connect remotely, and batch execute code, and this script could be executed in jEdit as a BeanShell script.

So far, I have Python code which successfully opens and closes the Telnet connection. It can do basic shell functions like call "dir". However, when I pass the exact same line that I use to execute SAS from command prompt on the remote server with a telnet connection in Python, nothing happens.

Is it possible the server is preventing me from executing code from a script? I use a "read_until" statement for the prompt before running any code.

Comment: Was Enterprise Guide included in your license? It is a great UI for executing code on the server.

Comment: You might want to use `Telnet.set_debuglevel` to get more information about what happens when you hit your read_until call.

Comment: @CarolinaJay65 We don't have SAS on the desktops. Not sure about Enterprise Guide, I'll have to ask the big guys about it.

@DavidK.Hess I am trying `print tnobj.read_until(prompt)` and it feeds all the telnet output up 'til I hit the prompt, so it looks like I'm virtually piping it into the Python shell. I don't actually get any errors, so I don't know what the debuglevel would do.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a few ideas...

The issue you are having above *may* be related to Local Security Policy settings in Windows (if it is running on a windows server).  I'm far from an expert on that stuff but I remember older SAS/Intranet installations required some rumaging around in there to get them working.

As an alternative to the approach you are trying above you could also setup a SAS session on the server that listens for incoming socket requests as per this article:

http://analytics.ncsu.edu/sesug/2000/p-1003.pdf

And finally... Not sure if this helps or not by I remotely execute SAS jobs using PSEXEC.  A description of how I set it all up can be found here:

http://www.runsubmit.com/questions/260/hide-sas-batch-jobs-winxp

Good luck

Comment: PsExec looks promising, I tried executing a little dummy program, but get that the access is denied. Our server is currently enabled for telnet, which I thought PsExec used. I tried supplying the user name and password. Any idea why this is?

Comment: Hmm sorry not sure.  There's a pretty active forum for psexec at [http://forum.sysinternals.com/pstools_forum8.html](http://forum.sysinternals.com/pstools_forum8.html) that may be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

[This paper](http://www.zolot.us/papers/SASWinUnix.pdf) outlines how you can use a Python script to connect to a Unix server using SSH, copy the SAS program written locally onto the server, batch submit it, and download the results back to your local machine, all using a BeanShell macro script for jEdit.